# UI widget in openGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm kinda new in Qt and openGL, I have a shape in my code in openGL and I need to place it on the UI widget. But the result of my code is like the picture below, my UI widget is on my shape. Can anyone help me with it?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
void Widget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix(); BackGround();
    gambi();
    if(is_dead==1) {
        DrawSquare(.8,.8,.8,1,1,1,1,.8);
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Please also post your relevant code.

Comment: OP, you should post your code in the question, not in the comments. @honk - thanks for editing this.

Comment: the code is added in the question

Comment: Can you explain what's what on the image? Which part of it is the shape, and which is the UI widget?

Comment: the square in the middle is UI widget and under it there is a shape of a person